# Syncing two Azure databases without using Azure Data Sync

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

I have a huge (500+ table) Azure SQL database (SQL Server). I need to create a clone of this database on Azure, and sync the two databases once daily. The clone is for reporting purposes.

What is the best way to implement the sync, outside of [Azure Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync)? We've experimented with Azure Data Sync, and it's proven unreliable due to the large size of the database.

I've looked into transactional replication, but I cannot find any documentation that states that it is supported from an Azure database to another Azure database. Geo-replication may be another option, though I'm not sure it is a good fit for this use case.

Comment: Have you tried HVR? https://www.hvr-software.com/product/

Comment: I haven't, but the Cloud Data Integration component looks promising. Thanks

Comment: how about creating a secondary replica as read only

Comment: I think Georeplication is also a good choice and lag is very minimal

Comment: @TheGameiswar After some more research, I'm thinking that Georeplication is the way to go. Now I just have to figure out if SSRS can connect to the geo-replicated db and function with read-only access.

Comment: Yes ,it can.I don't see why it cant

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, your best option is Azure Data Factory. It has a very easy to use Wizard as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-azure-copy-wizard). You can create yourself your copy activities as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-data-movement-activities) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-copy-data-from-azure-blob-storage-to-sql-database).

You can schedule ADF execution as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-scheduling-and-execution) too.

SQL Data Sync is in Preview and for that reason not recommended for Production environment.

Geo-Replication cannot scheduled for synchronization.

Another option is to use Cross-Database queries as mentioned [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/), and schedule execution of synchronization procedure created by yourself using elastic jobs or Azure Automation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a powerful tool. Curious as to why geo-replication is not a good option because it cannot be scheduled? The RPO, or lag time, for geo-replication is quite low. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-business-continuity

Comment: I did not recommended Geo-replication because synchronization cannot be scheduled and that is one of your requirements.